# Loop through list of objects inside object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, foreach, ienumerable

I'm using mvc and I'm passing the class called DataModel as my model to the view:

```
public class DataModel
{        
    public List<ServerStats> statsPerMonthPerServer { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the class ServerStats:

```
public class ServerStats
{               
    public string ServerID { get; set; }
    public List<ColumnData> ServerMonthStats { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the class ColumnData:

```
public class ColumnData
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public double Sum { get; set; }
}
```

I have managed to build my ModelData object, if I debug it, it looks like the information I want is in it, but I can not manage to print it out from the view. This is what I've tried to do:

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApp.Models.DataModel>
@foreach (var server in Model)
{
foreach (var month in server.statsPerMonthPerServer)
{
    @month.ServerID
    foreach (var column in month.ServerMonthStats)
    {
        @column.Date <br />
        @column.Sum <br />
    }
}    
}
```

And the controller where I build the DataModel and send it to the view:

```
DataModel dm = new DataModel();
dm.statsPerMonthPerServer = new List<ServerStats>();

foreach (var row in serverStats)
        {
                ServerStats ss = new ServerStats();
                ss.ServerID = row.ServerID;
                ss.ServerMonthStats = new List<ColumnData>();
                ColumnData cd = new ColumnData();
                cd.Date = row.Year.ToString() + "-" + row.Month.ToString();
                cd.Sum = row.ServerSum;
                ss.ServerMonthStats.Add(cd);                    
                dm.statsPerMonthPerServer.Add(ss);

        }


        return View(dm);
```

The error I get:
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'WebApp.Models.DataModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[WebApp.Models.DataModel]'.

I'm using lists but it says this is a dictionary, but I assume it is talking about my lists. I've read some about the IEnumerable interface. Do I have to implement it on all the classes except DataModel? I thought the model decleration on the top of the view took care of this? Any help would be preciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear. Your view is strongly typed to `IEnumerable<DataModel>` but from your controller action you passed only a single `DataModel` instance to the view. I guess you meant this:

```
@model WebApp.Models.DataModel
@foreach (var month in Model.statsPerMonthPerServer)
{
    <h3>@month.ServerID</h3>
    @foreach (var column in month.ServerMonthStats)
    {
        @column.Date <br />
        @column.Sum <br />
    }
}
```

Comment: @Xerion: Atleast accept a answer when your problem is solved.

Comment: @Veer you have to wait a couple of minutes before you can check it, calm down